# Sharepoint Edit Button that allows user to edit data from list in a webpart

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, button, sharepoint

I have a list in SharePoint that has different list columns (Birthday, Address etc.)

I want to add a function to this `Edit` Button in Vue.js that should allow users to edit the list columns directly in the webpart.

[image: Edit]

Here's how I created the button:

```
<div class="row" >
<button style="margin-left:1000px" @click="EditMode">Edit</button>
</div>
```

And here's what I have as a function (just a reference to the html of the list):

```
methods: {
    EditMode: function () {   
        window.open("https://MyLink", "_blank");    
    },
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I don't know what to write in the `EditMode` function. What I want to achieve is that right next to the texts (Progress, Position, Address etc.) the columns of the list should appear in such a way that the user can edit them. (Just like when you open the list manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use modal dialog to open edit form, sample demo.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //jQuery.noConflict();
        $(function () {
            new Vue({
                el: '#Vue_App',
                methods: {
                    EditMode: function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var options = {
                            // define a URL (and yes, you can pass params to that URL) or reference your HTML object, but NOT both!
                            url: '/Lists/SourceList/EditForm.aspx?ID=1&IsDlg=1',
                            tite: 'Modal Title',
                            allowMaximize: false,
                            showClose: true,
                            width: 430,
                            height: 230,
                            dialogReturnValueCallback: myCallbackFunction
                        };
                        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            })
            // The callback function expects a parameter of type SP.UI.DialogResult
            function myCallbackFunction(result) {
                switch (result) {
                    case SP.UI.DialogResult.OK:
                        alert("You clicked OK");
                        // reload data as necessary here
                        break;
                    case SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel:
                        alert("You clicked cancel or close.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        })

    </script>
    <div id="Vue_App">
        <button v-on:click="EditMode">EditMode</button>
    </div>
```